# Why can't I bind the margin property?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, properties, margin

I have a board of rectangles which I want to scale dynamically. I can set the Height and Width properties of the rectangle element. The only property that doesn't cooperate is the margin..

I tried binding the same property margin in my ViewModel to either width, height and margin and it only works well with the width and height. As soon as I try it on the margin property of the rectangle it takes a lot of time to load the window AND it eventually shows up with no margin at all..

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.Margin}" Fill="White" Height="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.Margin}" Width="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.Margin}"></Rectangle>
```

Property:

```
private int _margin = 5;
    public int Margin
    {
        get
        {
            return _margin;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A quick simple work-around would be to just use `Border` instead of `Rectangle` for now. I'll try to re-create what you got later when I have time because that is curious though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it! 
It seemed to be a problem to use int or double as margin.. margin is of type Thickness! Thanks for all the help anyway!

```
private Thickness _vakMargin;
public Thickness VakMargin
{
    get
    {
        return _vakMargin;
    }
    set
    {
        _vakMargin = value;
    }
}
```

I did set it for all 4 margins with:

```
new Thickness(someDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might have been with the way in which you're binding because I was not able to reproduce the issue.  Perhaps you could post more code to determine the exact cause.  However, the following worked for me:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyRectangle x:Key="myRectangle" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource myRectangle}">
        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Path=MyWidth}" Height="{Binding Path=MyHeight}" Margin="{Binding Path=MyMargin}"  />
</Grid>
```

CLASS CODE:

```
public class MyRectangle
{
    public double MyMargin { get; set; }
    public double MyWidth {get; set;}
    public double MyHeight {get; set;}

    public MyRectangle(double dHeight, double dWidth, double dMargin)
    {
        MyHeight = dHeight;
        MyWidth = dWidth;
        MyMargin = dMargin;
    }
}
```